# "Damped" wave equation with Fourier method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, laplace-transform, wave-equation

The problem I was trying to solve is the following PDE problem

> $$\begin{cases} \partial_{tt}^2 u = \partial_{xx}^2 u -\gamma\partial_t u \\[5 pt]
> u(0,t)= u(\pi, t) = 0 \\[5 pt]
> u(x,0) = (\sin2x)^4 -{1\over 5}\sin 10x \\[5 pt]
> \partial_t u(x,t)|_{t=0}=0
> \end{cases}\tag 1$$

with the *Fourier series* method. But I got stuck on the calculations.

What I've done is, first thing first, to evaluate the initial condition to eliminate that fourth power, which can be easily done, and I've got

$$
u(x,0) = {3\over 8}-{1\over 2}\cos4x +{1\over8}\cos8x-{1\over 5}\sin10x
$$

This says to me that the solution ought to be of the form

$$
u(x,t) = \sum_n a_n(t)\sin(nx)+b_n(t)\cos(nx)
$$

or simply by using the complex exponential, which doesn't change much. I then used the ansatz in the PDE to get two ODE's for the coefficients $a_n(t), b_n(t)$

$$
\sum_n(a''_n(t)\sin(nx)+b''_n(t)\cos(nx))= \\ =-\sum_n(a_n(t)\sin(nx)+b_n(t)\cos(nx))-\gamma\sum_n(a'_n(t)\sin(nx)+b'_n(t)\cos(nx))
$$

and got, equating the coefficients

$$
a''_n(t)= -\gamma a'_n(t)-a_n(t) \\
b''_n(t)= -\gamma b'_n(t)-b_n(t)
$$

which are the same equations: the equation of a damped harmonic oscillator. To find the solution we search for the solutions of the polynomial equation

$$
\lambda^2 +\gamma\lambda +1 = 0
$$

which are

$$
\lambda_1 = -{1\over 2}\left(\gamma+\sqrt{\gamma^2-4}\right)\;\;\;\;\; \lambda_2 = -{1\over 2}\left(\gamma-\sqrt{\gamma^2-4}\right)
$$

Clearly the solution for the ODE's depends on the value of the "damping coefficient" gamma

$$
\gamma^2-4 \gt 0 \implies \color{red}{a_n(t) = c^a_1e^{\lambda_1 t}+c^a_2e^{\lambda_2 t}}\\
\gamma_2-4\lt 0 \implies \lambda_{1/2} = \mu\pm i\nu \implies \color{orange}{a_n(t) = c^a_1 e^{(\mu+i\nu)t}+c^a_2 e^{(\mu-i\nu)t}} \\
\gamma^2-4=0\implies \lambda_1=\lambda_2=\lambda \implies \color{green}{a_n(t)=c^a_1 e^{\lambda t}+c^a_2 t e^{\lambda t}}
$$

and the same goes for $b_n(t)$. But then jumped to my mind that the solution would become very ugly! Knowing my professor I think that there could be a easier way to solving this.

> **Question 1:** In my solution, am I headed in the right way?
>
> **Question 2:** Is there a simpler method to solve this problem?
>
> **Question 3:** I thought about using Laplace transform but the initial condition make matter worse: could this be a viable way?

Comment: "Damped" rather than "Dumped", I'm guessing...

Comment: Ops ahah Thanks @user254433

Comment: Dampened? Damped sounds like something got wet.

Comment: @mathreadler I guess that it would be better to write *dissipative wave equation*. Surprisingly, it is easy to find some very serious research articles about the *damped wave equation* and the *damped oscillator*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting it short, the solution is "ugly", I might guess your professor meant for a nicer initial condition to force many fourier coefficients to zero out..

Anyways, most of your solution so far is fine. You should get that, through SepVar assuming $u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)$ (or your eigenvalue technique, similarly)

$$\begin{align*}
X(x) &= c_n \sin{(nx)}\\
T(t) &= B e^{-\frac{t}{2}}\left(\gamma_n \cos{\left(\frac{t}{2}\gamma_n \right)}+\sin{\left(\frac{t}{2}\gamma_n \right)}\right)
\end{align*}$$

Where $\gamma_n = \sqrt{4n^2 - 1}$, $n = 1, 2, ...$

Cool, our solution to our problem is

$$u(x, t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n \sin{(nx)}e^{-\frac{t}{2}}\left(\gamma_n \cos{\left(\frac{t}{2}\gamma_n \right)}+\sin{\left(\frac{t}{2}\gamma_n \right)}\right)$$

The not so cool thing is our orthogonality relation gives us a pretty disgusting integral to solve. The formula for our $c_n$'s follows

$$c_n = \frac{2}{\gamma_n \pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\left(\sin^4{2x}-\frac1{5}\sin{10x}\right)\sin{(nx)}\, dx = -\frac{2}{\pi \gamma_n} \left[\frac{384((-1)^n - 1)}{n(n^4 - 80n^2 + 1024)} \right]$$.

Note for $n = 4, n = 8$, that $c_n = 0$, and whene $n = 10$, $c_n = -\frac{1}{5\sqrt{399}}$.

Hence

$$u(x, t) = e^{-\frac{t}{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n \sin{(nx)}\left(\gamma_n \cos{\left(\frac{t}{2}\gamma_n \right)}+\sin{\left(\frac{t}{2}\gamma_n \right)}\right)$$

with the above formula for the coefficients.

Comment: I also want to add that solving boundary value problems by way of transform method is not advisable, but possible. You would arrive at the same infinite series solution by way of contour integration, see here for an example with laplace transforms: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2547535/wave-equation-pde-with-inhomogeneous-boundary/2548022#2548022

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Crystal clear! I'm from the phone app so I don't know if it has accepted and voted your answer, when I'll be home I'll check! Thank you again

Comment: @DavideMorgante It seems that $\gamma = 1$ for the damping coefficient is implicitly assumed here.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is the same as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3222097/418542), but with a specification of the initial data
$$
u(x,0) = \sin^4 2x - \tfrac{1}{5}\sin 10x = f(x)\, ,
$$
which is consistent with the boundary conditions at $x=0$ and $x=\pi$.
As such, it is also a sub-case of Exercise 4.4.3 p. 142 of (1). Hence, we have
$$
u(x,t) = e^{-\gamma t/2} \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} A_n \left(\cos \beta_n t + \frac{\gamma}{2\beta_n} \sin \beta_n t \right) \sin nx \, , \qquad \beta_n = \sqrt{n^2 - \tfrac14 \gamma^2}
$$
with $A_n = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} f(x) \sin nx\,\text dx$, for weak damping $0\leq \gamma < 2$. Using trigonometry, one writes
$$
f(x) = \tfrac{3}{8} - \tfrac{1}{2} \cos 4x + \tfrac{1}{8} \cos 8x - \tfrac{1}{5}\sin 10x \, ,
$$
from which the coefficients $A_n$ can be obtained by linearity.
Finally, the only nonzero coefficients are $A_{10}=-\frac15$, and $A_n = \frac{2}{\pi} \frac{768}{n (n^2 - 64) (n^2 - 16)}$ for odd natural integers $n$.

---

*Note*: The above solution seems consistent with the one in @DaveNine 's answer where apparently $\gamma=1$ is implicitly assumed.

*Note*: this equation is also known as telegraphers' equation or simply telegraph equation.

(1) R. Habermann, *Applied Partial Differential Equations; with Fourier Series and Boundary Value Problems*, 5th ed., Pearson Education Inc., 2013.